# Contacts export problems with Google Contacts Preview

Tags: google-contacts

I tried to export contacts from Google Contacts Preview but was told to go to old contacts to do so but there was no "export" contacts on the toolbar just import contacts. what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Click **More > Export...** .
[image: More > Export]

Detailed instructions, from [Export Gmail contacts into CSV file - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en&ref_topic=3396994)

> 1. Sign in to **Gmail**.
> 2. At the top left, click **Gmail > Contacts.**
> 3. Click **More > Export...** .
> 4. Choose whether to export all contacts or only one group.
> 5. Select the format in which you'd like to export your contacts' information. Note that some of these formats can lose some contact information.
>
>    - To transfer contacts between Google Accounts, use the **Google CSV** format. This is the recommended way to back up your Google Contacts.
>    - To transfer contacts to Outlook, Yahoo! Mail, Hotmail, or various other apps, use the **Outlook CSV** format.
>    - To transfer contacts to Apple Address Book, use the **vCard** format.
> 6. Click **Export**.
> 7. Choose **Save to Disk > OK**.
> 8. Select a location to save your file, and click **OK**.