# Scraping Directory contents from Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-contacts, export

Does anyone know of a good way to scrape the information from the Directory in Google Contacts? I saw this [How to download all directory contacts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85768/how-to-download-all-directory-contacts).

I tried to run it by following the steps layed out, but it just returns as "Unidentified". Any idea how to fix it? The issue may be volume related as there are around 1,500 contacts I am trying to export.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contacts export problems with Google Contacts Preview](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78093/contacts-export-problems-with-google-contacts-preview)

Answer (score -2):

In case you only want to export (without coding), you can use this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mlkgbjmmgdmmlggeemddlpkfefmbnnnf) to export directory contacts as CSV:

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/150891)